# How to pass data from a route to a pug file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, pug

I have a pug file called books.js where I am rendering a form based on an :id and filling in the text fields in the form with values passed in from a model in sequelize by using findById()

**books.js**

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Book.findById(req.params.id).then(function(book){
    res.render('update-book.pug', {book: book, title: "Update Book"}) 
    console.log(book)
  })
 });
```

this is the pug file that I am trying to render with values determined based on their id, I am using the word **book.** after value because it's my understanding that the function parameter `book` from books.js should contain data

```
extends layout.pug

block content
  h1= title

    form

      p
        label(for='title') Title
        input#title(name='title', type='text', value=book.title)
      p
        label(for='author') Author
        input#author(name='author', type='text', value=book.author)
      p
        label(for='genre') Genre
        input#genre(name='genre', type='text', value=book.genre)
      p
        label(for='year') Year
        input#year(name='year', type='text', value=book.year)
      p
        input(type='submit', value='Update Book')
    form(method='post', action='/books/8/delete', onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this book?');")
      p
        a.button(href='/') Cancel
      p
        input(type='submit', value='Delete Book')
```

in my terminal I get this message

`sequelize deprecated Model.findById has been deprecated, please use Model.findByPk instead node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:4208:9`

and in my browser I get this error:

[image]

can someone help?

Comment: Have you tried using findByPk instead?  What does that do?

Comment: You need to JSON.decode(JSON.encode(data)) then pass the result into the view. Also you can use Book.findOne({where: {id: req.params.id}}) this will give only one result.

Comment: I tried to use findByPk, but that also doesn't work

Comment: It's saying that your `book` variable is being returned as `null`. So, your `Book.findById` is returning null. It could be because it did not find any matching book in database with specified id, OR possibly because of this function being deprecated. Certainly, you should use the alternate solution if it has been deprecated.